# Blackberry Momentics IDE/Ubuntu 64: Error when creating/importing a debug Token

Tags: blackberry, momentics

I use Momentics IDE 2.1.2 with Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64 bit.
Since Version 2.1.201406041640 I get an error when I try to deploy an app to the device or register a new device to the IDE:

```
Debug Token: Required
Packaging failed:1
Fehler:Hauptklasse com.qnx.bbt.nativepackager.BarNativePackager konnte nicht gefunden werden
```

It's impossible to create debug tokens for devices using the IDE. But without the token I can't debug the app.

I can create and deploy debug tokens to the devices using the command line tools blackberry-debugtokenrequest and blackberry-deploy but the IDE doesn't accept these tokens for import.

I think there is something wrong with a java class path.
**Does anyone use Momentics IDE with Ubuntu?

Has anyone solved the problem?**

Next lines I found in the IDE log:

```
!ENTRY com.qnx.tools.bbt.core 4 0 2015-10-25 09:46:22.042
!MESSAGE Error creating debug token
!STACK 0
com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.signing.DebugTokenLoadException: Packaging failed:1
Fehler: Hauptklasse com.qnx.bbt.nativepackager.BarNativePackager konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
at com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.signing.BarSignerTool.loadDebugToken(BarSignerTool.java:679)
at com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.signing.BarSignerTool.createDebugToken(BarSignerTool.java:786)
at com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.signing.IDebugTokenManager$Impl.createDebugToken(IDebugTokenManager.java:229)
at com.qnx.tools.bbt.internal.ui.preferences.SigningUIUtils.createAndUploadDebugToken(SigningUIUtils.java:361)
at com.qnx.tools.ide.bbt.target.ui.manager.DeviceDebugTokensPage.completePage(DeviceDebugTokensPage.java:278)
at com.qnx.tools.ide.bbt.target.ui.manager.NewDeviceWizard$5$1.run(NewDeviceWizard.java:249)
at com.qnx.tools.ide.bbt.target.ui.manager.NewDeviceWizard$11.run(NewDeviceWizard.java:480)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 2):

BlackBerry has not published the debug symbols for 10.3 but you can work around it by going to the preferences -> BlackBerry -> targets and checking "Allow debugging and profiling "

Comment: Thank You!!!! Was starting to get very frustrated and now I can test my app on 10.3.3 using Momentic IDE. Thank You again :)